# String values are not parsed correctly into boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, parsing, boolean

Following code parses the string URL param 'verified=false' to boolean

```
  const verified = searchParams.get("verified");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(verified);
    let isVerified = Boolean(verified);
    console.log(isVerified);
    let message = isVerified
      ? "User succesfully verified by email!"
      : "verification failed!";
    setMessage(message);
  }, []);
```

according to that, change the state of the message.

But the browser log show

> page.js:14 false
> page.js:16 true

Two logs look different and the line 14 is a string indeed. What's happening in here?

I tried with

```
let isVerified = !!verified;
```

I think this operator do the same. But still no good!

Answer (score 1):

`verified` is string, so you have to compare it to a string, because `Boolean("false")` returns `true`.

I'd suggest you to write something like this:

```
function stringBooleanToBoolean(stringValue: string): boolean {
  return stringValue.toLowerCase() ==== true.toString()
}
```

edit:
any non-empty string is truthy, so if you have `"aa"` it is truty, and an empty string is falsy, like `""` is falsy
unfortnuately there is no built-in way to determine if a string represents a true boolean or a false boolean

regexes can be used as well, so something like `/true/i` can do the same as the script above.
please note that you have to be prepared to case-insensivity as well

Comment: Ah I got it! I thought the Boolean() parses like parseInt('5') ==> 5 (explicit values) Thanks for the answer 

Comment: Mostly welcome! Please mark it as the accepted answer, so the topic can be archived.